# How to optimize the usage of interface object when in one case you need optional properties, but not in another one?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, types, interface, dry

I have the following interface:

```
interface IUserInfo {
    name: string,
    surname: string,
    dateOfBirth: Date
}
```

In some places of my app I need to be sure developer provides an object of IUserInfo with all properties to a function:

```
const someFunc = (state: IUserInfo) => {
    // I want to get an error if developer tries to pass an object without name, surname or dateOfBirth
}
```

In other cases I need to have possibility to pass an object of the same type, but with optional properties, so user should be able to pass any combination of name/surname/dateOfBirth or nothing.

The easiest way is just implement two interfaces, one with required properties and another one without it. But I feel there is better approach exists to do it allowing don't repeat yourself.

How can realize my requirements the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to just mark all the fields as optional, you can use built-in `Partial<T>` type like this:

```js
type IPartialUserInfo = Partial<IUserInfo>;
// now type IUserInfo = {
//    name?: string | undefined;
//    surname?: string | undefined;
//    dateOfBirth?: Date | undefined;
// }
```

You can try it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO1Uhge2QG8BYAKGUuRDgFsIAuZTMKUAcwG5yrmBXKDXpMWbEFx5UAJnEgB5GACFgUMAAsmAEVkRuZAL7lyYAJ4AHFKgAKcVcDgAbLDjyEAvMht3HAHgzYoXAIAPj1yBHwQFmQIAA86MwcITCZrWzB7JwCg-ABtAF1kD1zJSiJ9ABpS4iFGZAByesrqokwBWqZG5ooqIhl5JRV1JhAIAHdkbUgACgBKCuo6Oq7yfM4gA).